# Difference between lipo -thin and -extract

Tags: macos, static-libraries, lipo

What is the difference between `lipo -thin arch_type` and `lipo -extract arch_type [-extract arch_type...]` when used to get a "single architecture" static library from a fat static library?

The documentation says:

> **-extract** arch_type [-extract arch_type...]
> Take one universal input file and copy the arch_type from that
> universal file into a universal output file containing only that
> architecture. This command requires the -output option.

> **-thin** arch_type
> Take one input file and create a thin output file with the specified arch_type.  This command requires the -output
> option.

But to me it seems just that `-extract` allows multiple architectures to be extracted, while `-thin` only allows one architecture at a time.
Is the result of the two commands the same or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `extract` it is possible to have a universal output given multiple architectures to extract.  With `thin`, you cannot. You can only output a thin.

Comment: So if I use `extract` with only one architecture, do I get the exact same result as `thin`?

Comment: You do; what matters is that if you intend to make a thin, you use thin.  If the operation is variable, or you intend to make a universal binary, then you would choose extract...

Comment: With only one architecture the output is only similar and the universal fat file will still have a bigger size. Just tested this with the bash executable and extract produced 656KB while thin created a 640KB exe. I guess that the fat file still has some additional headers so for minimum size thin would be better. Not sure if a fat exe with just one arch might have some advantages over a thin exe.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that `thin` removes specific architectures from a binary file, while `extract` extracts a specific architecture from a binary file.